# Mobile Connect API to resubscribe contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

We want to re subscribe contact in Mobile Connect All Contacts. The Contact status in All Contacts-Mobile Table is "Unsubscribed"
Is it possible to re subscribe mobile contact using REST API without sending SMS notification? How can we do this through automation?